sharing excel dashboard with BI through whatsApp
i have an excel dashboard with a slicer and when I am trying to share the file it self through WhatsApp , it is making error about the connections and the Bi when the user try to click the slicer , is there is any way to share the file with the whole functionality without going through Power Bi or share Point ? the user is using a mac and I am sending the files from windows

Yes, Excel can be used on Android phones and tablets. Download and install the Microsoft Excel app from the Play Store on your Android device. Power BI offers a set of mobile apps for iOS and Android mobile devices. In the mobile apps, you connect to and interact with your cloud and on-premises data, also you create reports in Power BI Desktop as well  dashboards, and view dashboards and reports, in the Power BI report service https://powerbi.com ☺
